# Make a sibling div not push its brother far over to the left

Tags: html, css

I have a toop tip that I'd like to display when a user hovers over a button. The tooltip is a div that appears in the correct place.

[image: tooltip1]

however, once a file is uploaded the `<div>` that the file information appears in, pushes the <`div>` of the tooltip way over to the right.

[image: tooltip2]

CSS FOR TOOLTIP

```
.expl {
padding-top: 11px !important;
border-radius: 3px;
color: whitesmoke;
background-color: cornflowerblue;
padding: 7px 9px 5px 9px;
display: none;
float: left;
position: relative !important;
top: 13px;
right: -17px;
display: none;
height: 35px;
-webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35);
-moz-box-shadow: 2px 2px 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35);
box-shadow: 2px 2px 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35);
}
```

FOR ADJACENT DIV TO THE LEFT

```
text-align: center;
float: left;
display: inline-block;
```

Is there  anyway I can get this tooltip div to always appear right next to the button, so that it sits above the container, and isn't pushed away by it?

Thank you

Comment: You could always have the tool-tip on a different z-index layer, pushing it in front of the other content. The disadvantage is that you'll need to get the screen/document position of the button, so you can position the popup accurately. Pretty easy, zillions of tutes to get mouse or element position.

Comment: If the popup allways appears at the same spot, use absoulute positioning and z-index. If not you have to use js to get its positon accordiong to the position of the button

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally I would use a separate wrapper `<div>` for the upload button and set that wrapper to `position: relative;` and put the tooltip inside that wrapper and use `position: absolute;` unless you are purposefully trying to have the tooltip affect the flow of the page.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using position:absolute for the tool tip? This will ensure it does not move when other elements on the page change.

Comment: wouldn't it be in an incorrect position if the user re-sized the page? Thank you.

Comment: If the parent element (doesn't even have to be the direct parent) uses position:relative and has a defined height and width you will not have this problem.

Answer (score 0):

put tooltip div before upload div

```
<div class="expl ...
<div clas="upload-button-wrapper ...
```

and make position absolute and margin-left to more than width of button

```
.expl {
position: absolute;
margin-left:100px; ... // more than upload button width
```

because after upload the render will be different and another div containing files list loaded, and it's logic to make the tool-tip be shifted, so the best way to put it before upload div

and you may try it without top and left, may be better or according to your layout

Answer (score -2):

Pretty? Nope. Functional? Yup. Here's how I would do it if I'd been up for 20 hours and wanted to knock something together quickly. As always unforseen project constraints may render the solution worse than useless. ymmv (The 2nd through to the 5th function are unused, just part of a template)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function byId(e){return document.getElementById(e);}
function newEl(tag){return document.createElement(tag);}
function newTxt(txt){return document.createTextNode(txt);}
function toggleClass(element, newStr)
{
    index=element.className.indexOf(newStr);
    if ( index == -1)
        element.className += ' '+newStr;
    else
    {
        if (index != 0)
            newStr = ' '+newStr;
        element.className = element.className.replace(newStr, '');
    }
}
function forEachNode(nodeList, func)
{
    var i, n = nodeList.length;
    for (i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        func(nodeList[i], i, nodeList);
    }
}

window.addEventListener('load', mInit, false);
function mInit()
{
    uploadBtn.addEventListener('mouseover', onBtnHover, false);
    uploadBtn.addEventListener('mouseout', onBtnLeave, false);
}

function onBtnHover()
{
    var btn = byId('uploadBtn');
    var xPos, yPos;
    xPos = btn.offsetLeft + btn.offsetWidth + 32;
    yPos = btn.offsetTop;

    var tgt = byId('popup');

    var btnHeight, popupHeight;
    btnHeight = btn.offsetHeight;
    popupHeight = tgt.offsetHeight;

    var vertOffset = (popupHeight-btnHeight) / 2;

    var styleStr = "display: inline-block; visibility: visible;";
    tgt.setAttribute('style', styleStr);
    tgt.style.left = xPos+"px";
    tgt.style.top = yPos-vertOffset+"px";
}
function onBtnLeave()
{
    var tgt = byId('popup');
    tgt.removeAttribute('style');
}


</script>
<style>
.controls
{
    border: solid 2px #aaa;
    padding: 16px;
}
#popup
{
    visibility: hidden;
    z-index: 2;
    position: absolute;
    max-width: 300px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    font-family: verdana;
    background-color: #6495ee;
    color: white;
    padding: 8px;
    font-size: 0.8em;
    box-shadow: 4px 4px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}
#popup b
{
    background: white;
    color: black;
    padding: 4px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    border: solid 1px #777;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class='controls'>
        <button id='uploadBtn'>Upload<br>file(s)</button>
    </div>
    <div id='popup'>To upload multiple files, <b>Shift</b> + click files in the dialog box..</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: No need for Javascript. This is fixable in CSS with two lines.

Comment: @brentonstrine - the ones used by `Cairo Solutions`?

Comment: No, more like @Pricey and @jonosma 's answers. [Here's a JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/brentonstrine/sraYm/) of the 2 lines of code. I used a `textarea` to make it simpler, but it would work with an upload button, or anything that changes size, too.

Comment: Thanks, I really appreciate the effort you've taken. Another trick to put into the box. :thumbs-up: EDIT: Chrome 28.0.1500.63 m, win7 - doesn't work. Dragging the text-area causes no movement in the tool-tip.